# Load an image with text and shape inside it and share it to social media

Tags: c#, html, blazor, .net-6.0

I have the plain blank image like below, however I did not know on how to put the dynamic text and shape on top of it and also inside it and also how to do the share to Facebook, Twitter, Instagram, WhatsApp and also Email, so when people click on that image, it will be redirected to the certain website (for example: https://www.mywebsite.com/DynamicTextHereThatGeneratedFromEarlier)

[image: Plain Blank Image]

What I would like to achieve is something like this with the dynamic text:

[image: Blank Image with the dynamic text]

Thank you very much